# Boost ASIO with OpenSSL Can't Read HTTP Headers

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I'm attempting to write a simple HTTP/HTTPS proxy using Boost ASIO. HTTP is working fine, but I'm having some issues with HTTPS. For the record this is a local proxy. Anyway so here is an example of how a transaction works with my setup.

Browser asks for Google.com
I lie to the browser and tell it to go to 127.0.0.1:443
Browser socket connects to my local server on 443
I attempt to read the headers so I can do a real host lookup and open a second upstream socket so I can simply forward out the requests.

This is where things fail immediately. When I try to print out the headers of the incoming socket, it appears that they are already encrypted by the browser making the request. I thought at first that perhaps the jumbled console output was just that the headers were compressed, but after some thorough testing this is not the case.

So I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction, perhaps to some reading material where I can better understand what is happening here. Why are the headers immediately encrypted before the connection to the "server" (my proxy) even completes and has a chance to communicate with the client? Is it a temp key? Do I need to ignore the initial headers and send some command back telling the client what temporary key to use or not to compress/encrypt at all? Thanks so much in advance for any help, I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: It will be helpful if you posted some code you have problems with.

Comment: Read the asio ssl examples. You should make async_handshake before any send/receive

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. The issue is that if I do a handshake when the client connects to the proxy, the browser becomes aware of this and flips out saying the cert isn't authentic and everything else. I'm trying to make a local transparent proxy so that the browser isn't aware that the content being exchanged over SSL is being filtered locally. Just for the record this might sound malicious but it's for an application where the client is aware that the local proxy is running, no malicious intent. :) I'll see if I can post some code.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS passes all HTTP traffic, headers and all, over a secure SSL connection.  This is by design to prevent exactly what you're trying to do which is essentially a man-in-the-middle attack.  In order to succeed, you'll have to come up with a way to defeat SSL security.

One way to do this is to provide an SSL certificate that the browser will accept.  There are a couple common reasons the browser complains about a certificate: (1) the certificate is not signed by an authority that the browser trusts and (2) the certificate common name (CN) does not match the URL host.

As long as you control the browser environment then (1) is easily fixed by creating your own [certificate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) and installing its certificate as trusted in your operating system and/or browser.  Then in your proxy you supply a certificate signed by your CA.  You're basically telling the browser that it's okay to trust certificates that your proxy provides.

(2) will be more difficult because you have to supply the certificate with the correct CN before you can read the HTTP headers to determine the host the browser was trying to reach.  Furthermore, unless you already know the hosts that might be requested you will have to generate (and sign) a matching certificate dynamically.  Perhaps you could use a pool of IP addresses for your proxy and coordinate with your spoofing DNS service so that you know which certificate should be presented on which connection.

Generally HTTPS proxies are not a good idea.  I would discourage it because you'll really be working against the grain of browser security.

I liked [this book](http://amzn.com/0201615983) as a SSL/TLS reference. You can use a tool like [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) to create and sign your own certificates.

Comment: rhashimoto what about cases when you set proxy for your system?